# Prim's Algorithm in the Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

I'm trying to build a MST from a graph defined with the Boost Graphic Library. After some fiddeling I realized that the example uses an adjacency list for graph representation like:

```
typedef adjacency_list <vecS, vecS, undirectedS, VertexProperty, EdgeProperty> Graph;
```

However, if I change the type of the <strike>EdgeList</strike> VertexList (2nd parameter) to `slistS` according to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:choosing-graph-type prim's algorithm will not work any more.
Does anyone know why there are such constraints and why it is not mentioned clearly in documentation?

**EDIT**

The compile-error message is not telling much about the actual problem:

> required from here

Comment: What does "will not work any more" mean? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: for starters, what the heck is `std::slist`?

Comment: `slist` is a singly linked list also known as forward_list

Comment: well, so much about documentation... :)

Comment: This does not solve your problem, but the second parameter is VertexList. If I had to guess your problem(you should provide the error message) it would be that you don't have a vertex index property map. In [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/prim_minimum_spanning_tree.html) you can find this quote in the vertex_index_map section: "Note: if you use this default, make sure your graph has an internal vertex_index property. For example, adjacency_list with VertexList=listS does not have an internal vertex_index property.". The only adj_list that has one by default is vecS.